# Count number of sentences in a string in SAS

Tags: count, sas

I was wondering if there is an easy way in SAS to count sentences in a string?

In pseudo code I would search for the index of every `.`, `?`, and `!`, and check if the index before that (`-1` or `-2`) is a character.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your sentences are correctly punctuated, there should be exactly 1 sentence per `?!.`, so in that case you can use `countc(my_string,'?!.')`. The main exceptions are probably interrobangs (`?!`,`!?`) and ellipses (`...`).

If your string contains lots of sentences with missing stops or double stops, one option is simply to cross your fingers and hope they more or less cancel out.

If there are lots of double stops but not so many missing ones, you could apply a regex to replace any run of consecutive stops with a single `.` before counting those, e.g. `countc(prxchange('s/[\.!\?]{2,}/./',-1,string),'?!.')`.

Comment: You could account for double stops or sentences puntctuated by both a question mark and exclamation point (called 'interrobang' apparently) by using regular expressions instead.

Comment: Either your regex should have `+` (or `{1,}`) instead of `{2,}` to also replace single question marks and exclamation points with periods; or your `countc` function should keep counting `?` and `!` on top of `.`.